# Extract substring with a specific pattern in MySql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a text field which looks like:

```
option[A]sum[A]g3et[B]
```

I want to get the text which is inside the `[ ]` without duplicates.
Meaning to get:

```
A
B
```

There can't be a case of double like `[ [ ] ]`.

I know this is a horrible way to save data in databases. I can not change how the data is saved. I just need to get a very specific (one time) information from this column.

I tried to do:

```
SELECT substring_index(substring_index(sentence, '[', -1),']', 1)
FROM (SELECT 'THIS[A] IS A TEST' AS sentence) temp;
```

This gives me `A`, but it will not work for many `[]`.

I thought of using regex however I don't know how many `[ ]` I have.

How do I do that?

Comment: You have already asked this question today; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37026194/how-to-get-information-between-two-specific-characters

Comment: @jarlh page not found, deleted I think.

Comment: @jarlh I deleted and re post to make it clearer.

Comment: Do you have a list of possible values inside the braces?  Otherwise, this is rather difficult in MySQL, which doesn't even support table-valued functions.

Comment: @GordonLinoff values inside the `[]` are letters and numbers.

Comment: @mm Yes it is possible, please do not remove your question again

Comment: @lad2025 what is possible?

Comment: @mm To get result as you need, I'll provide answer when SQLfiddle start to work

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not job for `DB` but it is possible:

```
CREATE TABLE tab(id INT, col VARCHAR(100));           
INSERT INTO tab(id, col) 
VALUES (1, 'option[A]sum[A]g3et[B]'), (2, '[Cosi]sum[A]g3et[ZZZZ]');      

SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM (
  SELECT id, RIGHT(val, LENGTH(val) - LOCATE('[', val)) AS val
  FROM
  (
    SELECT id, SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(t.col, ']', n.n), ']', -1) AS val
    FROM tab t 
    CROSS JOIN 
    (
     SELECT a.N + b.N * 10 + 1 n
       FROM 
      (SELECT 0 AS N UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) a
      ,(SELECT 0 AS N UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) b
    ) n
    WHERE n.n <= 1 + (LENGTH(t.col) - LENGTH(REPLACE(t.col, ']', '')))
  ) sub
) s
WHERE val <> ''
ORDER BY ID;
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/277447/1/0)**</kbd>

Note:

Depending on `col` maximum length you may need to generate more numbers in `CROSS JOIN` section. For now it is up to 100.

Output:

[image]

How it works:

1. Generate number table with `CROSS JOIN`
2. Split string based on `]` as delimeter
3. `RIGHT(val, LENGTH(val) - LOCATE('[', val))` remove the part up to `[`
4. filter out empty records
5. Get only `DISTINCT` values

Inner most query:

```
╔════╦══════════╗
║ id ║   val    ║
╠════╬══════════╣
║  1 ║ option[A ║
║  1 ║ sum[A    ║
║  1 ║ g3et[B   ║
║  1 ║          ║
╚════╩══════════╝
```

Second subquery:

```
╔════╦═════╗
║ id ║ val ║
╠════╬═════╣
║  1 ║ A   ║
║  1 ║ A   ║
║  1 ║ B   ║
║  1 ║     ║
╚════╩═════╝
```

And outermost query:

```
╔════╦═════╗
║ id ║ val ║
╠════╬═════╣
║  1 ║ A   ║
║  1 ║ B   ║
╚════╩═════╝
```

> I need the result of query per row.. not combined

So add simple:

```
WHERE n.n <= 1 + (LENGTH(t.col) - LENGTH(REPLACE(t.col, ']', '')))
  AND t.id = ?
```

**EDIT 2:**

> *see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8ee95/1 your query works partially for my data. I also changed the type to longtext.*

You want to parse JSON in MySQL. **As I said before parse and get value in application layer.** This answer is only for demo/toys purpose and will have very low performamce.

If you still insist on SQL solution:

```
SELECT id, val,s.n
FROM (
  SELECT id, RIGHT(val, LENGTH(val) - LOCATE('[', val)) AS val,n
  FROM
  (
    SELECT id, SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(t.col, ']', n.n), ']', -1) AS val, n.n
    FROM (SELECT id, REPLACE(col, '[]','') as col FROM tab) t
    CROSS JOIN 
    (
     SELECT e.N * 10000 + d.N * 1000 + c.N * 100 + a.N + b.N * 10 + 1 n
       FROM 
      (SELECT 0 AS N UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) a
      ,(SELECT 0 AS N UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) b
      ,(SELECT 0 AS N UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) c
      ,(SELECT 0 AS N UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) d
      ,(SELECT 0 AS N UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) e

    ) n
    WHERE n.n <= 1 + (LENGTH(t.col) - LENGTH(REPLACE(t.col, ']', '')))
  ) sub
) s
WHERE val <> ''
GROUP BY id, val
HAVING n <> MAX(n)
ORDER BY id,n;
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8ee95/24/0)**</kbd>

Output:

```
╔═════╦═════════════╦════╗
║ id  ║    val      ║ n  ║
╠═════╬═════════════╬════╣
║  1  ║ CE31285LV4  ║  1 ║
║  1  ║ D32E        ║  3 ║
║  1  ║ GTX750      ║  5 ║
║  1  ║ M256S       ║  7 ║
║  1  ║ H2X1T       ║  9 ║
║  1  ║ FMLANE4U4   ║ 11 ║
╚═════╩═════════════╩════╝
```

**EDIT 3:**

> *What exactly is done there? Why do you need n*

`CROSS JOIN` and entire subquery is only tally table. That'is all. If `MySQL` has function to generate number sequence (like `generate_series` or prepopulated number table there is no need for `CROSS JOIN`.

Number table is needed for [`SUBSTRING_INDEX`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index):

> **SUBSTRING_INDEX(str,delim,count)**
>
> Returns the substring from string str before count occurrences of the delimiter delim. **If count is positive, everything to the left of the final delimiter (counting from the left) is returned.** If count is negative, everything to the right of the final delimiter (counting from the right) is returned. SUBSTRING_INDEX() performs a case-sensitive match when searching for delim.

Comment: thank you. Can you explain how it works? I think you expanded my initiate intention. I need it to work on a specific string. Not on wide table... If it have 5 relevant rows in the table I will run the query 5 times. one time for each row.. I need the result of query per row.. not combined.  The string datatype is `longtext`

Comment: see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8ee95/1  your query works partially for my data. I also changed the type to `longtext`.

Comment: @mm Check updated. And for next time, please show your real data first, not oversimplified example :)

Comment: Thank you. Can you explain the cross join? What exactly is done there? Why do you need n ? and why it runs from 1 to 1000? does it means this support up to 1000 rows in result? If I read it correctly the cross join only create a sequence number series?